# React native, FlatList does not re-render when inside of Navigator

Tags: react-native

I have a FlatList that needs to re-render when my data changes. Everything works fine when the FlatList is located in render(), but when I put it inside of a navigator it shows the correct data at first, but never updates at setState().

The following code works:

```
render(){
  return (
      <NavigationContainer style={styles.navigation}>

      <FlatList
    data={global.context.state.listData}
    extraData={global.context.state}
    renderItem={({item, index})=> global.context.renderItem(item, index,null)}
    numColumns={1}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
 }
```

The code below doesn't work:

```
render(){
  return (
      <NavigationContainer style={styles.navigation}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="List" component={this.ListScreen}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={this.FavoritesScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={this.SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
 }

ListScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <FlatList 
    data={global.context.state.listData}
    extraData={global.context.state}
    renderItem={({item, index})=> global.context.renderItem(item, index,navigation)}
    numColumns={1}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes because setState only re renders what's in your render function, however the Navigator knows not to re render it's routes. Looks like you need a context consumer, this article is using react and not react native but the points about contexts should still hold true: https://dev.to/evangunawan/react-context-the-easy-way-stateful-component-bh0

Comment: @bryanstevens314 Using context provider/consumer solved the problem, Thanks!